# What will happen if we use the same label for different object

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

In LaTeX, what will happen if we use the same label for different object?

I have tested the example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 1 \label{1}
    \item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{theorem}
    
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{1}
    
\end{theorem}



\begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b \label{1}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I have tested `\ref{1}` in different locations and it seems that `\ref{1}` always points to 2, i.e. `\item b \label{1}`. Is it true that if a label is used many times, the ref will always point to the last one?

This is in fact an incorrect way of labeling.
But I found labels like `1, 2, 3` really convenient for enumerate enviornment.
So, what would you suggest to label items in enumerate environment?

Comment: you get a warning in the log if you reuse a label name `There were multiply-defined labels`, and you shouldn't ignore that. It is not only a bad habit it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will add that this is in fact incorrect in my post. What format would you suggest labeling items in an enumerate environment?

Comment: I never use numbers in labels, but something that refers to the content, e.g. item:apple-color for `apples are red or green`.

Comment: labels should be a meaningful internal identifier unrelated to the number `\label{fermats-last-theorem}`  on the theorem, `\label{apple}`  `\label{orange}` on your shopping list itemize. Let latex worry about the numbers.

Comment: @above Thanks. I will begin accustoming myself with using content for labels from now on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But when a proposition is not famous enough to have a name, the label would be very long if we use its content as the label, which is grammatically correct, but not very convenient. For instance, imagine that the Fermat's Last Theorem did not have a name, I would label it as `a^n+b^n=c^n admits only trivial solutions for n ge 3.`. Is this the best way? How would you label it?

Comment: Just use something short so that you know what to put in `\ref{..}` to refer to it. the _wole point_ of using `\label` is that the numbers are genearted automatically and will change as you edit the document you if you label an item as `\label{1}` and refer to it as `\ref{1}` then edit the document so that this is the second item, it will work, but confuse any human reader looking at the source that `\ref{1}`  generates a reference to item **2**

Comment: Using the full content is just as bad as using a number, you neeed to be able to edit the text add a comma fix a speling without having to change the `\label`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, then what about something like `solution for a^n+b^n=c^n`? Or would you please give an example how to label Fermat's Last Theorem supposing it did not have a name?

Comment: it really doesn't matter. unless you reference it from elsewhere it does not need a `\label` If you do need to to you can add `\label{wibble}`  and use `\ref{wibble}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, thanks for your comment. I actually meant how to label things we would need to quote. (I understood things not quoted did not need a label.) I would try to change my labeling habit. Thanks for the comment.